# Count cars using bboxes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, count, object-detection

I have trained an s2anet detector to detect cars in drone videos. The visual ouput of the detector is as shown in the following image:

[image: Car_Detections]

I want to count how many cars cross a certain line, for example a line from point A (766,642) to point B (766,676). Is there a way to count them using the bounding boxes that are created or do I have to use background substraction method to try to re-detect them? Also as an output I have a CSV file which contains the coordinates of each bounding box. Maybe I can use this to count the cars. Any ideas?

Comment: first, tracking by association: assign each box to the closest track from previous frames (within plausible distance assuming cars don't go faster than the speed limit or something). end tracks when cars leave, create tracks when cars enter -- then, establish two lines instead of one, for hysteresis. -- then, determine if a track progresses from being in front of the first line, to being behind the second line. if a track is between both lines, no change of state -- tracking (1) would require an inner and outer area for the same hysteresis

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to know when the line and the bbox intersect you can use cv2.intersectConvexConvex:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

line = np.array([(100, 100), (200, 100)], dtype=np.int32)
bboxes = np.array([[(350, 80), (370, 80), (370, 120), (350, 120)], [(150, 80), (170, 80), (170, 120), (150, 120)]], dtype=np.int32)
for i in range(len(bboxes)):
    intersect_area, intersect_contour = cv2.intersectConvexConvex(line, bboxes[i])
    if intersect_contour is not None:
        print(F"line intersection with bbox {i} detected")
```

Comment: i used Point,Polygon from shapely.geometry and i counted how many times a point intesects with a polygon using .within() . Then i printed all the True and False but still have a long way to go as my results are above the real count of cars.